# SwaggerEndpoint exception: Request path must not end in a slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle

I'm following MS docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Cvisual-studio-xml) to use Swagger UI in ASP.NET core 2.0 web API.

After performing all steps, when I run my project locally in VS 2017 I receive following exception.
System.ArgumentException: **"Request path must not end in a slash"**

The exception occurs when I add following line as mentioned in documentation:

```
c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
```

When I dont' set RoutePrefix and go "https://localhost:44392//swagger/v1/swagger.json", I get a JSON formatted output. I was expecting a UI. 
Any solution or hint would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
An error message appears when I try to access it through "https://localhost:44392//swagger"

```
{"data":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.EntityTagHeaderValue..ctor(System.String)'."}
```

Comment: Try https://localhost:44392//swagger

Comment: Thats because you are opening the json defintion itself. the default url is something like /swagger

Comment: @JMad, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out. 
There are few things that I need to do:

1. Remove "c..RoutePrefix = string.Empty;"
2. Access Swagger UI via https://localhost:<'port'>/swagger/
3. Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles v2.0.0.0 nuget package to resolve 'method not found' error.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access https://localhost:44392/swagger for the UI like it is shown in the documentation. The link you posted leads you to the JSON document which is intended